# What is the appropriate semantic HTML tag for a short blurb underneath a heading?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics, wai-aria

What is the best semantic HTML tag for a short blurb underneath a heading? I'm sure this has a name since a large amount of websites have this, but I can't seem to find it or the appropriate tag.

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>

<h2>Section Title</h2>
<div>Short blurb about this section</div>
<div>Section content</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the small tag in place of the p tags, like I did below. This page should help https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

```html
<header>
   <h1>HTML 5.1 Nightly</h1>
   <small>A vocabulary and associated APIs for HTML and XHTML</small>
   <small>Editor’s Draft 9 May 2013</small>
</header>
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I just found, too. It seems like it just needs to all be wrapped in a `<header>` tag.

Comment: Yeah that'll work as well. Glad ya got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question not long after posting this. According to [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements), I should wrap the heading and blurb (they call it a subtitle) in a `<header>` tag:

> Example 4: In the following example the title and tagline for a news article are grouped using a `<header>` element. The title is marked up using a `h2` element and the tagline is in a `p` element. A sample CSS styled rendering of the title and tagline is provided below the code example.
>
> ```
> <header>
>   <h2>3D films set for popularity slide </h2>
>   <p>First drop in 3D box office projected for this year despite hotly tipped summer blockbusters,
>   according to Fitch Ratings report</p>
> </header>
> ```
>
> [image: Title:'3D films set for popularity slide' in a large, bold, dark blue Serif font style. Paragraph: 'First drop in 3D box office projected for this year despite...' in a smaller, dark grey, Sans Serif font style.]